# Creating login system with encrypted password

Tags: android

I have a password created with Visual Basic.net

I have got this code from the developer:

```
Public Function encripta(ByVal cadena As String) As String
        Dim uEncode As New System.Text.UnicodeEncoding()
        Dim bytClearString() As Byte = uEncode.GetBytes(cadena)
        Dim sha As New System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed()
        Dim hash() As Byte = sha.ComputeHash(bytClearString)
        Return Convert.ToBase64String(hash)
    End Function
```

This is the stored value for the generated password in a MySQL database:

```
5PYNCqbX89O2pklLHIYbmfZJxvnsUauvIBsg8pcyfJU=
```

I need to provide a login system for an android app based on an existing MySQL database. I can access all rows from the user table, but the password field is created using another system.

I don't know how can I create a login system using this password.

I only know that the password is 0 in this case.

I need to compare the password entered by the user with this encrypted password, or am I wrong?

Comment: Please provide us with some detailed question, are you willing to encrypt the user entered password from the android app ?

Comment: @AntoineElMurr, I am developing and android app. I need to provide a login system based on an existing MySQL database. I can access all rows from the user table, but the password field is created using another system

Comment: okay I will look into with now I understand what you want

Comment: What you are using in your app kotlin or java ?

Comment: @AntoineElMurr, Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
try {
                String password = "test";
                byte[] bytes = password.getBytes("UTF-8");
                MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
                byte[] hash = digest.digest(bytes);
                String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(hash, Base64.DEFAULT);
            }catch (Exception e){

            }
```

Comment: it is encoding fine the string, but I need to compare a string entered in the android app with the encrypted sting received as password from the user

Comment: how you are getting the string in the android app?

Comment: yes, and I need to compare the encrypted received string with the password string entered by the user in the android app

Comment: okay password is the string entered by the user, you need to do base64.equals("YOUR_RECEIVED_STRING")

Comment: Ok, now I have two strings: the text entered by the user (password) and the encrypted password received from MySQL (enc_password). How should I use your proposal using both strings (password, encuentro_password) ?